# Redhat quitting process never works always have to kill it

Tags: redhat, unix, ruby-on-rails, unicorn

I am working on a RedHat server creating a unicorn process. I have two sets of these processes being created. I am able to QUIT one of the process fine and do so over and over again create it and QUIT it. The other process I am able to create but I am not able to QUIT it. I have to actually send in the KILL command like this.

```
kill -9 [process]
```

I was told by others that you should only do a kill -9 as a last resort. If the process is hanging or something to the like. Since this is a scripted process through Unicorn it probably wouldn't be smart to just kill it.

The question is how can I debug why one of these processes is not able QUIT but instead always requires that KILL command. Also these two processes are being created through a script using a RAILS_ENV variable in each to create it. So I assume they are being created with the same ownership and all that. I did verify ownership and permissions all look the same.

Any help would be great to track this down. Currently I have tried to use Strace with no luck.